# android app translation not working

Tags: android, string, resources, translation

It is really strange since I have made a few apps with the same structure and it always have worked before.

The thing is I have an app in some languages, Spanish, English, etc, with the proper res/values-es , res/values, etc

Default language is English in the google play app section and res/values is in english, but I'm receiving complaining for user that say they are viewing the app in Spanish, having the phone in English and being in the USA.

And the even more strange is that I am in Spain, and I configure the phone in English and I can view the app in English ...

So weird.

Any tips on this?

Comment: I don't know what lint is, sorry, can you ask it in a different way please? @Stephan Branczyk

Comment: I think i can make a res/values-en and copy there string.xml from res/values just in case default behaviour changed, but I want other opinions

Comment: Do you know which android handset and android  version it is on ? That way you can try testing using the device's emulator perhaps.

Comment: No, I don't have that information.

Comment: Lint is a static analysis tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html It's also accessible through the Android Developer Tools on Eclipse. Unfortunately, I'm not on my development machine now, or I could tell you which Eclipse menu to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but if the fix needed is urgent. A quick workaround would be to create a `res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml` resource until you can figure out what's truly causing this issue.

> [If the locale is ‘en-US’](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/), Android will look for a value of
>   “R.string.title” by searching the files in the following order:
>
> 1. ‘res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml’
> 2. ‘res/values-en/strings.xml’
> 3. ‘res/values/strings.xml’

Comment: I thought about that but, because of that string look order i discarded it since res/values exists and it would eventually find it, but I will try just in case, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, do the 'res/values-en/' folder as well, just in case. And personally, I wouldn't accept my answer just yet (you can undo the acceptance if you click on it again I believe). Someone else may be able to get to the root cause of your issue (which is what you were really asking in the first place).

Comment: I have just upload the new apk, hope it fix this strange issue!, If it is fixed, I'll mark yours as the correct answer @Stephan Branczyk

Comment: It has worked!, I also made a res/values-en-rGB , just in case. The user that told me the problem, now says that is fixed but a new user is saying that she has the same problem but I think that she has not updated, Anyway thank you for your answer